# How to use module in to my menu item

Tags: joomla2.5

I have an custom module for search location.Now i want to put this module in to one of menu item content page. I am using joomla 2.5. Any way how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solve it by use the `{loadposition}` method

For using the module into your content page go to `extension manager->plugin manager`.Then search for `Content - Load Modules` plugin enable it(if disable). Then set style to `no wrapping(raw output)`.

and then to your article manager and insert this line where you want to display your module

```
{loadposition myposition} //where myposition is the position of your module
```